# Dagger 2 problem in providing interface implementation

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm so new to Dagger and I have some error when I want to inject an interface implementation, I have an interface called `Mapper<K,V>` and it's implementation is `ArticleEntityArticleMapper`

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding]ir.siatech.newsappkotlinclean.domain.commons.Mapper<? superir.siatech.newsappkotlinclean.domain.entities.ArticleEntity,ir.siatech.newsappkotlinclean.presentation.entities.Article> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

And here is my codes:

```
 @Module
 abstract class MapperModule {
 @Binds
 abstract fun   providesArticleEntityArticleMapper(articleEntityArticleMapper: ArticleEntityArticleMapper)
        : Mapper<ArticleEntity, Article>
}

@Module(includes = [ViewModelModule::class])
abstract class ViewModelBuilder {

@Binds
abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}



@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule { 
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(NewsViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindNewsViewModel(newsViewModel: NewsViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

and here is my ViewModel :

```
class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor() :   BaseViewModel() {                 

@Inject                                                                   
lateinit var articleEntityArticleMapper: Mapper<ArticleEntity, Article>
}
```

EDIT :

```
@Singleton
@Component(
modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    UseCaseModule::class,
    MapperModule::class,
    DataModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class,
    ContextModule::class,
    NetworkModule::class]
 )
 interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<NewsApp> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
}

}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot adding `MapperModule`, I can't see it getting used.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak No, I've added it to my component, BTW I added my component implementation to the post

Comment: where is the code for `ArticleEntityArticleMapper`? That should look like : `class ArticleEntityArticleMapper @Inject constructor(...) : Mapper<ArticleEntity, Article> { ... }`. Also anything other than Android platform classes should use constructor injection i.e `class NewsViewModel @Inject constructor(private val articleEntityArticleMapper: Mapper<ArticleEntity, Article>) ...`